# Laravel - resolve class with dependencies AND execute the constructor of instantiated class

Tags: php, laravel, class, dependencies, construct

Consider this code:

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use App\Services\AnotherService;

class SomeService {
    public function someMethod() {
        $anotherService = \App::make(AnotherService::class);
    }
}
```

My intention is to get a class object with all its dependencies resolved. But in this specific case, I would like that the object's __construct has been executed as well. I have tried and by code above, the $anotherService object's __construct method is **not** executed.

Therefore I can achieve what I need by doing -

```
$anotherService = \App::make(AnotherService::class);
$anotherService->__construct();
```

Can it be done with single line instead of redundantly each time call construct method after instantiating the object? - Because that is what __construct method is made for - executing automatically. But I have noticed that for some reason Laravel's automatic dependency resolving skips the __construct execution.

Note, that `new AnotherService()` is not an option for me, as well as using the `__construct` method of `SomeService` class. I would like to make an object inside the `someMethod` method.

Class `AnotherService` currently does not have any dependencies. It has just some random variable updates inside the `__construct`, like:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->varA = true;
    $this->varB = 'Some Value';
}
```

Why do I need to resolve this class (instead of using `new AnotherClass()`)? - Simply because I want to test this call in unit tests by mocking it. For that I use this code:

```
$this->mock(AnotherService::class, function ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('anotherMethod')->andReturn(false);
});
```

And then finally I have to call the method to check the response:

```
$anotherService = \App::make(AnotherService::class);//<-- In this moment $varA and $varB are not set because the __construct did not execute!
$response = $anotherService->anotherMethod();

// Assert...
```

So, in this case, for example, if `anotherMethod` would use any of those variables, the tests would be incorrect because their values are not set.

Comment: _"Laravel's automatic dependency resolving skips the __construct execution."_ I don't see why this would the case as laravel's IoC internally calls `new` when injecting dependencies can you show the implementation of `AnotherService`

Comment: I updated my question. Please, check it again for more details.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am seeing similar behaviour, using `resolve()` the constructor of my service does not seem to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is either a mistake somewhere in your code or some misunderstanding.

The problem here is not in Laravel. The key here is the usage of Mockery. When creating a simple `Mock` for a class, its constructor is not invoked, and it's just a mock. When using `$this->mock(...)`, you just bind a concrete instance (mock) in the *container*. Thus, when calling its `make`, that ready mock is returned. Meaning, that `__construct` is neither invoked by Mockery, nor by Container.